# Hibernate Criteria - Fetching results from two tables without any association

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have been trying hard to implement a functionality of Search using Hibernate criteria. The requirement is bit vague. User could enter any text/word in the search field, the search has to be made through multiple tables which doesn't have any association between each other.

following are the two entity classes.

```
Table A (EntityClassA.java)
Table B (EntityClassB.java)
```

if a user enter "anycharecter" that should be searched in those two tables and should return fetched list(s) matching the entered character(s). *Also I want to store results from table A to List and result from Table B to List*.

I am not sure how this can achieved using hibernate criteria.

I could only manage to write this for one table.

```
public List<EntityClassAVo> search((string keywords){

List<EntityClassAVo> outputList = new ArrayList<EntityClassVo>();

Criteria criteria = etSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EntityClassA.class);
//applying restriction - as I need to search entered string in all columns. 
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("id", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("age", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
outputList = criteria.list();
return outputList;
}
```

**Question**

1) if its possible, How to write criteria for EntityClassB.java in the same "search" method?

2) if question 1 is possible, how to store results fetched from EntityClassA in one object and EntityClassB in another object?

3) If the above is not simple possible, i am probably going to ask to change the design ( only if, If i have a strong reason). - I am thinking of putting a intermediate table (Table X) between (Table A) and (Table B).

**[EDITED]** 
4) There is a scenario, where user wants to search results from either of 1 table or both. How we are going to check this condition?

Please help me to crack this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you simply write the same criteria for EntityClassB?

```
Criteria criteriaA = etSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().
            createCriteria(EntityClassA.class);
criteriaA.add(Restrictions.ilike("id", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteriaA.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteriaA.add(Restrictions.ilike("age", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

Criteria criteriaB = etSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().
            createCriteria(EntityClassB.class);
criteriaB.add(Restrictions.ilike("smth", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteriaB.add(Restrictions.ilike("rows", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
criteriaB.add(Restrictions.ilike("here", keywords, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

and then use, for example, Map: Entity -> List to return results

```
map.put(EntityClassA.class, criteriaA.list());
map.put(EntityClassB.class, criteriaB.list());
return map;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I am not able to get Map part. Can you please explain it in a bit, what would be the signature of Map here?

Comment: signature of Map can be `Map<Class<? extends Entity>, List<? extends Entity>>` if you have a basic class for you EntityClassA and EntityClassB or just `Map<Class<?>, List<?>>`. obtain data: `EntityClassA a = (EntityClassA) search("ololoolo").get(EntityClassA.class).get(0);`

Comment: Okay, so ? operator means "any class". The extends keyword may be used to qualify that to "any class which extends/implements an entity class?

Comment: I have edited my question (added question 4), not sure if this signature would work in that scenario? I though I would assign a flag or something , if user wants to take the result out from Table A, I would set flag=true and Criteria criteriaA and likewise for Table B, if he selects both options. To achieve this I thought of setting the key as 0 for the flag which is set false. not sure if you can correctly understand what i have written in this comment :), apologies in advance

Comment: hmmm.. `search` looks like DAO method, so I'd prefer to create two different methods like `searchA` and `searchB` istead of this, which will return simple lists. and then combine results in service method depending on user request